# tee for Windows?

Tags: shell, powershell, stdout

Does Windows provide the basic `tee` facility for copying standard input to an arbitrary set of files and then back out to standard output?

I generally download a generic `tee` program, but curious if something like this exists in powershell or something like that?

Comment: PowerShell is not for everyone so many will prefer to just download tee from http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Comment: What about cmd? I mean w/o downloading external tools is there a way to display the output of a program and write it into a file at the same time?

Comment: powershell is for everyone from Vista and up

Comment: @phuclv, well except for anyone working in a corporation that just locks up the entire powershell functionality, which is almost all of them

Comment: @Shodan no most companies I know do not lock powershell at all. They may lock the ability to run powershell scripts but there's no way to completely prevent users from using powershell as an interactive tool

Answer (score 45, accepted):

PowerShell sure does, the cmdlet is called Tee-Object. You can also use the alias **tee** if you're more used to the Unix-like approach:

```
PS C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator> help Tee-Object

NAME
    Tee-Object

SYNOPSIS
    Saves command output in a file or variable and displays it in the console.
```

example:

```
C:>get-process | tee -filepath C:\file.txt
```

this will send the output to `C:\file.txt` as well as the console.

Comment: There are also numerous ports of the original `tee` to Windows, but those can be easily found by one's favorite Internet search engine.

Comment: Right, actually I "carry" a zip file with me from environment to environment; tee being part of that toolkit, but just a fundamentally useful facility I was thinking just HAD to be part of Windows somewhere.

Comment: The powershell tee isn't quite identical to the "UNIX / GNU" tee you are familiar with. I would very much recommend carrying around the UnxUtils with you and invoking them in this case.

Comment: Thanks @joey, having ended up on this page while searching for tee for windows on a search engine

Comment: I can get it to work with some commands, but not with others. Weird...

Answer (score 3):

I just found a way to use the perl as alternative, e.g.:

```
CMD1 | perl -ne "print $_; print STDERR $_;" 2> OUTPUT.TEE
```

Comment: The post seems to ask for a PowerShell solution. Perl doesn't work on Windows in a native fashion so.... hmmmm

Comment: there's no perl in Windows by default

Comment: I have to make tee work on older Windows versions as well, where Tee-Object is not available. Not to mention that this works cross-platform if you replace the `"` with `'`. So this is a nice solution +1

Answer (score 1):

Native port of **tee** for Windows also exists, for example:

https://github.com/dEajL3kA/tee-win32/tree/master#tee-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

Use the native tee port from gnuwin32: https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm

Comment: note to reviewers: I could not post this as a comment, as commenting is not allowed to new users