# How can I use something like tail -f for a long taking process that only writes to a logfile in batch?

Tags: batch, logging

I have a long taking batch process in Jenkins (Unity3D to be exact) that doesn't provide any output to the console.

It only writes a logfile lets say `unityLog.txt` and does **not** produce any output to the console itself.

I need to display the output while it gets appended to the logfile in the console so it gets visible to the user via the Jenkins web interface.

So what I am currently doing is e.g. (more on the [Unity Command line argments](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html))

```
E:\Unity\2019.3.3f1\Editor\Unity.exe -quit -batchmode -projectPath E:\Projects\Example -executeMethod JENKINS.AutoBuilder.PerformBuild -logFile unityLog.txt -buildFolder E:\Projects\Example\Build

type unityLog.txt
```

The command actually runs in the project folder so this works but only displays the content of the file after unity finishes.

I have already read a lot questions similar to [Displaying Windows command prompt output and redirecting it to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file) which works great but they always assume the command itself produces any direct console output.

As said this is not the case here.

So what I would need is actually a form doing in batch what in bash I probably would do like (This is also just an example, unfortunately not a bash expert either ;) )

```
function MyLongTakingProcess()
{
    pid=$!

    E:\Unity\2019.3.3f1\Editor\Unity.exe -quit -batchmode -projectPath E:\Projects\Example -executeMethod JENKINS.AutoBuilder.PerformBuild -logFile unityLog.txt -buildFolder E:\Projects\Example\Build       

    kill $pid
}

touch unityLog.txt
tail -f unityLog.txt & MyLongTakingProcess
```

to permanently display added lines but cancel this as soon as the command has finished.

Any idea how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the documentation you linked (emphasis mine):

> Specify where Unity writes the Editor or Windows/Linux/OSX standalone log file. To output to the console, specify - for the path name. **On Windows, specify - option to make the output go to stdout**, which is not the console by default.

Than, as [this answer states](https://superuser.com/a/74128/403314) you can use `Tee-Object` in PowerShell to copy that stdout to a file to should you need it.

Comment: There are two issuea: `which is not the console by default` I will try again but I'm pretty sure to remember that I didn't see anything in the console when using `-`. That's the reason why I started this whole logfile workaround in the first place... Then also this is in general running in a batch script, not in the Powershell... But thanks for your input! Any little hint that brings me closer to a solution is very welcome!

Comment: Boy I tried again and you are right! This doesn't actually answer the question but totally solves all my trouble as the `-` option in fact simply produces the output I need to the console. As jenkins stores this ouput I don't need it in a file actually. I guess I only tried it without specifying this parameter at all so it didn't produce any output! I now don't even need the log file at all. Thanks to hint me on that again!

Comment: I didn't have time to reply earlier, but I suppose the note about the console was Unity-specific. You know, those in-IDE logs? And - is a fairly common placeholder for stdin/stdout in arguments which need a file.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question, you want the tail the log in Windows. If that's your use case, then have a look at [BareTail](https://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/). It's a Windows utility which tails log files, for real-time log analysis.

Comment: yeah I do not want to display it in an external tool. It has to be printed in the cmd console itself so it gets displayed to the user on the Jenkins webpage ;) But thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

I have found I can achieve what I was looking for doing the following

first I create the file (euivalent to `touch`)

```
echo. 2>test.txt
```

Then I start a "background" process for `powershell -c "get-content test.txt -wait"` (equivalent to `tail -f test.txt`)

```
start /b "logoutput" powershell -c "get-content test.txt -wait -ErrorAction Ignore"
```

the additional `-ErrorAction Ignore` hides any errors from the console.

Then I start the actual long taking task which generates output to `test.txt` using

```
start /b "long" /wait LONGTEST.bat
```

in order to wait for it to finish

Then finally I simply use

```
del test.txt
```

Deleting the file makes the powershell exit with an error. The error however I surpessed using `-ErrorAction Ignore`.

---

So in total

```
echo. 2>test.txt
start /b "logoutput" powershell -c "get-content test.txt -wait -ErrorAction Ignore"
start /b "long" /wait LONGTEST.bat
del test.txt
```

Using this I now see the full log in the console and am able to "kill"(make fail exit) the `get-content` process in the end.